# Xcode Swift - Make a button that will keep track of peoples press

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I need help writing a code that will

- Has a button and a label
- when the button is pressed by a parse user the label automatically adds 1, example when 10 parse users click the button the label would turn to 10. If 24 parse users clicks on the button the label will change to 24.
- Basically the code would keep count of how many parse users have clicked on the button and displys how many users have clicked it on the label.

*I haven't started done anything on this, if someone could help me out it would mean alot. Thank You.*

Answer (score 0):

This question is not specific enough to answer.  The code for creating a button that increments by one and storing the data in parse is trivial.  Do you want 1 user to only be able to like the photo once and do you want that like to be tied to the user that liked it?  If so you will need to use relation data.

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
var relation = user.relationForKey("likes")
relation.addObject(post)
user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
    // The post has been added to the user's likes relation.
    } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
   }    
}
```

The documentation for parse is excellent.  I suggest reading more of it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and concern . And yes please i wanted each user to  like it once not twice. like a simple like button you see everywhere else :/ if you could help me that would be so amazing! thank you once again. @twtr and btw idk if this makes it easier i just want a button and a label when ever a parse user clicks the button the label increases by 1 if that same parse user clicks it again the label number decreses back to 0.

Comment: I doubt you will find someone on stack overflow that will do this for you as it is a site focused on specific programming questions.  I really recommend  the documentation for Parse.  If you have a fair understanding of swift or even how to code in general it will not be hard to implement, it will just take  time.

Comment: im trying my best right now :/ i got the code that you were talking about working.. but it doesnt save it to parse when i click the button it changes to 1 witch is what i want but... when i rerun the app it changes back to Label. @twtr